# How to "properly" name a "reduced" form of a word when it's used in a compound word?

Tags: morphology

I am trying to find a proper name for forms, that do not exist by themselves, but kinda happen when this word is combined with another to form a compound word, example in Estonian:

ratsionaliseerimine ("rationalizing, rationalization") => Gen. "ratsionaliseerimise" (Genitive is used in compound words for non-basal components of compound)

ettepanek ("suggestion")

but compound word is "ratsionaliseerimis/ettepanek". As you can see, the word final "e" of "ratsionaliseerimise" has been lost due to de-deduplication

How one would call such a form ("ratsionaliseerimis") ?

thanks!

Comment: Sometimes "combining form"

Comment: If indeed combining or compound(ing) forms are what you’re looking for, a more obvious example is the Graeco-Latin vowel ‘suffix’ _-o-_, which can be used (even productively in English now) to make compounding forms of nouns. For example, most (all?) words with the suffix _-logy_ ‘study (of)’ effectively ends in _-ology_ because of this _-o-_, and it’s used in various other contexts as well – Ind**o**-European (Indus/India), Angl**o**-Irish (Angles/English), typ**o**graphy (type), sapi**o**sexual (sapient), etc.

Comment: Could call it syncope

Answer (score 2):

Just based on the examples that you give, there are two plausible analyses. One is that final /e/ deletes whenever it is followed by another word in a compound. The other is that final /e/ deletes when followed by /e/ in a compound. Whichever is the correct analysis, there is no specific technical term attached to "first part of a compound which is adjusted by deleting a vowel". There is a term that refers generally to "phonologically adjusted forms of morphemes", namely *allomorph*, which also refers to the three pronunciations of the regular plural suffix in English, or the various stem changes in the inflection of an Estonian adjective like *halb* "bad".

Comment: to clarify: this (reduction) only occurs when the next compound begins with a vowel; or similar situations. any non-reduced form is simply an "inflected form". I was hoping there is a technical for such forms that never occur by themselves but "kind-a" occur when being placed in specific sound context. And yeah, I was not looking just for "first part of a compound".. it could be any part (but the last, in this case)

Comment: This is where the "root/stem" metaphor works best, in SAE language (which Estonian is not, being Uralic). There are often several stem classes, each with a different bunch of possible stems, which may be restricted to certain constructions and inflections and never occur alone.